# Check if more than 1 refresh schedule recurrence per day exists

Tags: powershell, powerbi

The following code is intended to get a list of all powerbi reports on our PBI Reporting Server, check if each report has more than 1 refresh plans.

- if a report has more than 1 refresh plan AND if there is more than 1
  refresh schedule recurrence PER DAY (i.e. 2 plans that make a report
  refresh twice a day), then report it as a violation.
- The only exception is if the plans contain "_AP" in their
  description, then those would be fine, even if they refresh twice a
  day.

I am stuck at the part where i have to check for dailyrecurrence count. How do i accomplish this?

```
-and $refreshPlanValue.dailyrecurrence.count -gt 1
```

here is the code i have so far:

```
$loopCount = 1
$violation = $false
$PBI_Reports_Array = @()

$refreshPlanQueue = New-Object System.Collections.Queue

try {
    $PBI_Reports_Array = $(Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $($webPortalURL + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports")) 

    foreach ($reportPath in $PBI_Reports_Array.value.path) {
        try {
            foreach ($refreshPlan in $(Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $($webPortalURL + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports(path='" + $reportPath + "')/CacheRefreshPlans")))
            {
                $refreshPlanQueue.Enqueue($refreshPlan)
            }

            while($refreshPlanQueue.count)
            {   
                $refreshPlanValue = $($refreshPlanQueue.Dequeue()).value

                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($($refreshPlanValue))) { 
                    write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | No Refresh Plan Exists for this Report!";
                }
                else {
                    if ($refreshPlanValue.count -gt 1 -and $refreshPlanValue.dailyrecurrence.count -gt 1) #if there are more than 1 Refresh Plan(s) and if more than 1 refresh/day schedule exists, check if Description has "_AP", otherwise, violation!
                    {   
                        0..($refreshPlanValue.Description.length-1) | ForEach-Object {

                            if ($refreshPlanValue.Description[$_] -like "*_AP*")
                            {
                                write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($refreshPlanValue.Description[$_]) | $($refreshPlanValue.ScheduleDescription[$_])" #-foregroundcolor cyan;
                            }
                            else
                            {   $violation = $true

                                write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($refreshPlanValue.Description[$_]) | $($refreshPlanValue.ScheduleDescription[$_]) | This Report violates the $1 Refresh/Day rule!" #-foregroundcolor red;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($refreshPlanValue.Description) | $($refreshPlanValue.ScheduleDescription)" #-foregroundcolor magenta;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            write-host "$loopCount | ERROR! $($error[0])`r`n$($error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)`r`n$($error[0].ScriptStackTrace)"
        }
        $loopCount++
    }
}
catch {

}
```

one way i can think of is to do it foreach plan and then count, but is there a way to avoid introducing another inner loop and just counting all the recurrences at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

its as simple as:

```
if ($refreshPlanValue.count -gt 1 -and $refreshPlanValue.Schedule.Definition.Recurrence.DailyRecurrence.count -gt 1) {...}
```